# Can you print the values of a JSON array in an AWS, using a JMESPath query?

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to list all the SQS queues in our account using `aws sqs list-queues` into a bash one-item-per-line output.

Problem is it comes through as a JSON object

```json
{
  "QueueUrls": [
    "url",
    "url",
    "etc..."
  ]
}
```

I can use JMESpath to get this
`aws sqs list-queues --query 'QueueUrls[]'`

but that gives me:

```json
[
   "url",
   "url",
   "etc..."
]
```

## Question

Is it possible to print the output from a JSON array, using a JMESPath query in a one-per-line style?

From:

```json
{
  "key": [
    "string",
    "string",
    "string"
  ]
}
```

To:

```
string
string
string
```

## What I want

I want:

```bash
url
url
url
```

## What I've tried

- Using `aws sqs list-queues --query 'QueueUrls[]' --output text`

  I get the urls all in one line:

  ```bash
  url   url   url   etc...
  ```
- I've also looked at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59060069/19433976) but nothing I tried to put into the query gave me the flat-output

## Work around

Currently I'm doing `aws sqs list-queues --output text | sed -E 's/^.+\s+(.+)$/\1/'` to extract the url line from the text output.

(Definitely also posible with `awk` but the `sed` regex was the thing my mind did first)

## Why I want it

I want to use the output in a bash script I'm writing. I want to `grep` the lines and do some other processing on the output.

In this case it was simple to do the `--output text` trick but for more complicated AWS objects I'd like to know if it is possible using JMESPath.

Comment: NO need for the join, just the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by joining the elements of the JSON array with the [`join` bulletin function](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#join).

You have two possible and equivalent syntaxes:

1. Chaining the function on the array, and using the [current node — `@`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#current-node)

   ```
   QueueUrls.join(`\n`, @)
   ```
2. Wrapping the whole array in the function

   ```
   join(`\n`, QueueUrls)
   ```

<sup>*Note: backticks — `` ` ``, in JMESPath is the delimiter for a [literal expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions).*</sup>

---

So, your AWS command ends up being:

```bash
aws sqs list-queues --query 'QueueUrls.join(`\n`, @)' --output text
```